# How to add items to a dictionary

Tags: python

people. I'm python newbie. I have two def functions as below under a class.

```
def add_item(self, itemID, itemlist):
    lines = []

    self.itemID = itemID
    self.itemlist = itemlist

    for line in self.itemID, itemlist:
        lines.append(line)
```

and

```
def get_keys(self):
    i = []
    i.append(self.itemID)
    return i
```

If I do

```
example.add_item('abc', item list)
example.add_item('abcd', item list)
example.add_item('abce', item list)
```

then when I do

```
example.get_keys()
```

It should give:

```
['abc', 'abcd', 'abce']
```

but mine only gives the latest one that is `['abce']`.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix?

Comment: I *strongly* suggest you read the Python [tutorial](http://docs/python.org) ...

Comment: There are no dictionaries anywhere in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to add several couple of `key` and `item_list` to your example, and be able to retrieve the keys you added so far ? The easiest is to store the `keys` and the `itemlist` in two lists

Assuming that you initialize your object as such

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.itemID = []
   self.itemlist = []
   ...
```

Now, your `add_item` can simplify in

```
def add_item(self, itemID, itemlist):
    self.itemID.append(itemID)
    self.itemlist.append(itemlist)
```

and your `get_key` is only:

```
def get_keys():
    return self.itemID
```

---

- Note that the `get_key` is exactly the one you have suggested, just simpler (no need to create a temporary list).
- When you do

  ```
  lines = []
  for line in self.itemID, itemlist:
      lines.append(line)
  ```

  `line` first takes the value `self.itemID`, then `itemlist`. Eventually, your `lines` is  just `[self.itemID, itemlist]`. Probably not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new key to a dictionary, just assign it.

```
dict['new_key'] = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_item(self, itemID, itemlist):
    lines = []
```

You are initializing your `lines` variable with `empty list`...

So, each time you invoke this method, it create a new list, and add the item to it..
You can rather return your `lines` from this method and store it in some variable where you are invoking this method..

Or, just declare `lines` as `instance variable`.

```
example = Example();
example.lines = []
example.lines.extend(example.add_item(itemId1, item_list1));
example.lines.extend(example.add_item(itemId2, item_list2));
```

Or, you can rather add your `itemId` and `list` to dictionary `__dict__` of your class..

```
dict[itemId] = value;
```

** NOTE: - Just saw that, you have not used your `for-loop` correctly.. You don't iterate over `two` iterable like this..

You need to go through a good Python Book.. Or rather, Python Documentation..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
i.extend(self.itemID)
```

Might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting the item each time you add it.

When you call add_item, you are creating this variable "lines" that is never used again, and item_id and item_list are over-written with the new inputs.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see: You are iterating over two elements at once which is usually done by using `zip()`, at least if both elements are lists. Otherwise just use the container you want to loop over.

```
for id,line in zip(self.itemID, itemlist):
    lines.append(line)
```

But I don't see any `dict`...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the built-in method `update`:

```
example.update({'Key':'value'})
```